# how can I use mongodb array(simple and embedded array) elements as php indexed array

Tags: php, mongodb

I want to print all array and embedded array elements one by one...

Db structure:

```
  Users: [
        { 
           "_id" : "1", 
           "uname" : "Eminem", 
           "pro_img" : [ "img1", "img2", "img3" ]   // this values
           "gener" : "rap",
           "about" :
                [
                  { "child_name" : ["child1", "child2" , "child3"] },   // and this values
                  {"dob" : "15-07-1970"}

                ] 
         },

        { 
          "_id" : "2", 
          "uname" : "Armin", 
          "pro_img" : [ "img21", "img23", "img34" ]
        }
]
```

I write the code following way

```
<?php 
      include 'vendor/dbcon.php';
      $documentlist = $Users-> find(
                       ['uname' => "Eminem"],
                       ['projection' =>  ['_id' => 0, 'pro_img' => 1]]
                    );
        foreach ($documentlist as $doc) {
        echo var_dump($doc);
    }
?>
```

Output

```
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)#14 (1) { 
   ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(1) { 
   ["pro_img"]=> object(MongoDB\Model\BSONArray)#10 (1) { 
   ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=> array(3) { 
   [0]=> string(4) "img1" [1]=> string(4) "img2" [2]=> string(4) "img3" } } } }
```

But I want to store in following way:

```
$info= array("img1", "img2", "img3");
```

Also the embedded values with same condition  ['uname' => "Eminem"]

```
$info= array("child1", "child2", "child3");
```

so that i can use it as a simple php array...

Comment: this is an assumption schema ....if my schema structured this way then how can i print the values ....please help

Comment: the duplicate question code i dont understand ....please help me here